# Problema com importação de arquivos em diferenter diretórios

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com um problema em usar arquivos diferentes em diretórios diferentes, essa é a árvore de diretórios do meu projeto:

```
DeatHash
├── deathash
│   ├── deathash.py
│   ├── dictionaries
│   │   ├── dictionary_test.txt
│   │   └── dictionary.txt
│   ├── files
│   │   ├── archive_test.txt
│   │   ├── cesar.txt
│   │   └── vigenere.txt
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
├── doc
├── __init__.py
├── LICENSE
└── test
    └── test_deathash.py
```

Estou precisando acessar o módulo principal **deathash.py**, caminho:

> **DeatHash/deathash/deathash.py**

a partir do módulo **test_deathash.py**, caminho:

> **DeatHash/test/test_deathash.py**

Já tentei colocar init.py nos diretórios(obs: coloque com os _(underline) antes e depois do 'init', com o .py no final), também tentei usar no **test_deathash.py**, o código

```
from deathash.deathash import *
```

Outra solução que achei é a de se adicionar ao path o diretório que contém a função que vou usar, porém aparentemente essa solução ficaria ineficaz se o projeto for levado para outro diretório, o que pode vir a aconter, então se você souber de outra solução para o problema por favor me ajude.

Comment: Já cogitou a possibilidade de utilizar virtual env?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Sim, eu ia configurar um virtual env aqui para o projeto, mas achei que apenas iria ajudar na questão de 'libraries' e das suas versões...

Comment: Também, mas você pode utilizar o virtual env para instalar o seu módulo, mesmo em desenvolvimento, com a flag `--editable` do PIP e assim conseguir importar normalmente nos arquivos de teste.

Comment: Não - virtualenv é vida - eu não discuto na minha resposta, mas ela vai funcionar melhor se você tiver um virtualenv. Sem um, o seu pacote e outros que você precisar vão ficar instalados direto no Python do sistema.

Answer (score 2):

O seu "deathash" como está é um "pacote" de Python (uma coleção de vários módulos).

Via de regra, o que o Python faz para achar pacotes é:

1. Ele procura o nome do pacote na pasta em que está rodando (onde você digitou "python" no terminal, ou na pasta onde está o arquivo ".py" que você clicar, se não for pelo terminal)
2. Na biblioteca padrão do Python (instalada junto com o interpretador atual, que pode ser um virtualenv)
3. Na pasta "site-packages" que fica junto com o interpretador. Nessa pasta também podem existir alguns arquivos especiais que apontam para pacotes instalados em outros lugares - só que esses arquivos são complicados, e criados pelo "distutils" ou "setuptools" a partir de código que em geral fica num arquivo `setup.py` no seu projeto.
4. em qualquer pasta que esteja na variável de ambiente `PYTHONPATH`.

Depois que o programa está em execução,  todas essas pastas ficam em ordem na lista que é apresentada na variável `sys.path`. Então, simplesmente colocar a pasta onde está a pasta "deathash" manualmente na lista sys.path vai funcionar (com os métodos `.append` ou `.insert` normais de lista)

Mas essa não é a maneira mais "limpa" de fazer isso - já que nesse caso, o seu teste vai depender de achar o pacote principal "sozinho".

O "mais correto" é que o seu deathash esteja instalado - ou no Python principal, ou no virtualenv atual - mas isso exige a criação de um arquivo "setup.py" apropriado.

Isso não é difícil - um setup.py mimio pode ter umas 10 linhas - veja  documentação aqui https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#basic-use

Exemplo:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name="HelloWorld",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

Para o exemplo de 4 linhas de `setup.py` do link acima funcionar, você só precisa: instalar o `setuptools`, escrver o seu setup.py, e chama-lo com a opção "develop": `python setup.py develop` - isso vai criar um link permanente no site-packages do seu ambiente de Python para o seu pacote, e ele vai *sempre* ser encontrado.

E, por fim, a forma mais simples de todas, que não exige nenhuma alteração, execute o seu script de testes chamando ele da pasta onde estão os diretórios `deathhash` e `tests` (no caso a  `DeatHash`): dessa forma tanto  `deathash` como `tests` estarão visíveis como pacotes. (a regra "1" acima: ele procura o pacote na pasta da qual o Python está rodando)

```
python test/test_deathash.py
```

Ou, se você estiver usando o [pytests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/):

```
py.test test
```

Answer (score 0):

Para quem também tiver essa dúvida, é bom saber que você fez certo em colocar os arquivos `__init__.py` nas pastas. Sem isso não funcionaria.

Para seu caso específico, no arquivo `test_deathash.py` comece da seguinte forma:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../deathash/')
from deathash import *
```