# Como executar um script python de um diretório dentro de outro script que está em outro diretório?

Tags: python, script

Tenho um script python "pai":

```
import subprocess

# Executar script de outra pasta
if __name__ == '__main__':
     cmd = "main.py -u abcd -p 1234"
     subprocess.call(cmd, Shell=True)
```

Que chama o script "filho" main.py (que está em outro diretório com todos os seus módulos e subpastas), também com os dois parâmetros, conforme exemplo acima.

Não consigo achar uma forma de chamar/executar o script, ele estando em outro diretório. Todos as informações que encontrei aqui no site mostram importações para arquivos que estão na mesma pasta e/ou para chamar funções do modulo "filho", mas eu quero executar o script como se estivesse rodando ele no prompt de comando.

Tem como?

Comment: Se o `main.py` está em outro diretório, deve especificá-lo no comando, algo como `outra/pasta/main.py`

Comment: tentei já com o caminho especificado, não dá certo. Não entendi bem se é por conta dos parâmetros. Talvez o comando usado não seja o que eu estou usando.

Comment: Eu coloquei algo como `cmd = "C:/Users/EU/PycharmProjects/Pasta1/main.py -u ABCD -p 1234" subprocess.call(cmd, Shell=True)` Mas não funcionou.

Comment: quando você usa o `subprocess` com a opção `shell=True` a string com o caminho do arquivo nao é interpretada pelo Python - ela é passada para o S.O. - e ele não reconhece "/" como um separador de diretórios - re-rescreva o caminho com `\ ` , colocando sempre duas de cada vez - `\\\` - para evitar que seja usada como um caractere de escape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idealmente, cada diretório ou programa que for feito para ser usado por projetos independentes, deve ser transformado em um pacote instalável - para isso, o método mais comum é criar um arquivo `setup.py`  (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281961/500). Quando isso é feito, basta usar `import <nome_do_outro_projeto>` (mesmo que seja um único arquivo), em um ambiente do Python em que ele esteja instalado e tudo funciona.

Como isso envolve alguma burocracia, nem sempre é o ideal para momentos em que só precisamos ter algo funcionando - tudo o que realmente é necessário é que o diretório onde esteja o outro arquivo seja um componente da lista em `sys.path` .
Se você for no modo interativo e digitar

```
import sys
sys.path
```

vai ver uma lista de strings, cada string é uma pasta onde o Python vai buscar pacotes e módulos para importar. Ela começa com uma string vazia, `''`,  indicando que o primeiro diretório é o diretório atual - por isso `import <arquivo>` funciona para importar `arquivo.py` na mesma pasta.

Então, se você está trabalhando com uma estrutura fixa de diretórios, e não pretende mudar scripts de lugar (ok, se estiver montando um docker, péssimo se for uma máquina desktop de uso de desenvolvimento: não é produtivo copiar estruturas de diretórios para outra máquina), é só, antes do comando `import`, importar o `sys` e alterar a lista `sys.path`, incluindo nela o diretório onde está o script que quer importar:

```py
import sys
sys.insert(1, "/camino/para/outra_pasta/")
```

E a partir daí, você pode fazer `import <arquivo>`  e vai funciona.

Nesse ponto chamo a atenção:  a ideia de um sistema com vários arquivos é usar os `import` e tudo ser executado dentro do mesmo `job` de Python, mesmo que se use módulos como `multiprocessing`.

Quando você usa `subprocess.call` você inicia uma outra tarefa completamente separada do processo atual - pode ser um programa em Python, mas pode ser qualquer outro programa - e a comunicação tem que ser feita, se houver "manualmente" pelo stdin e stdout. Não é necessariamente ruim - mas só pode ter algumas vantagens se forem coisas bem independents mesmo - por exemplo, o projeto que chama o outro é uma interface gráfica genérica para disparar o outro job. Mas mesmo nesses casos, se o outro projeto é em Python, se você importar o outro projeto como uma biblioteca - você pode chamar as funções e instanciar classes do outro projeto, passando parâmetros que estão disponíveis no projeto que "faz a chamada".

Resumindo - tente organizar seus projetos de forma que sejam importáveis, e possam ser usados como  um único processo de Python, usando o "import".

Comment: Seria uma vantagem no meu caso o subprocess, pois o processo de execução dessa call demora um pouco e o script "pai" poderia continuar a trabalhar em outras informações.

Comment: ok - quando tem vantagens claras e não tem problemas, pode ser feito. Mesmo assim, para algo mais permanente, e não "algo pra funcionar agora", pode valer a pena ver se pode ser feito com `multiprocessing` :  você mantem a visibilidade das funções e classes em Python no outro processo, mas pode chamar funções para serem executadas num processo a parte, enquanto o atual não é interrompido.

Comment: Acho que tens razão, vou procurar informações sobre como implementar o `multiprocessing`. Importar o diretório como pacote e implementar o `multiprocessing`.

Comment: se colocar uma pergunta como essa um pouco mais expandida - com os cmainhos, o conteúdo dos arquvos de um lado e de outro, e com esse assunto - transformar o subprocess.call em multiprocessing,  eu respondo aqui.

Comment: Blz... postei a pergunta um pouco mais expandida. Veja se já dá para entender melhor. Tem alguns dados ali que não posso por, mas acho que da forma que coloquei agora ficou mais detalhado. [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/470771/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-executar-um-script-python-que-est%c3%a1-em-outro-diret%c3%b3rio)