# É possível executar um script python que está em outro diretório?

Tags: python

Tenho um script python "pai":

```
# Executar script de outra pasta
if __name__ == '__main__':
     cmd = "main.py -username abcd -password 1234"
     subprocess.call(cmd, Shell=True)
```

Que chama o script "filho" main.py (que está em outro diretório com todos os seus módulos e subpastas), também com os dois parâmetros, conforme exemplo acima.

```
def main(argv):
    global username = "" #argv
    global password = "" #argv
    acessa_site_com_login #criar csv na pasta para cada texto acessado, demora uns minutos para finalizar

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Então eu tenho em pasta 1 o "pai" e pasta 2 com o "filho".

Não consigo achar uma forma de chamar/executar o script, ele estando em outro diretório. Todos as informações que encontrei aqui no site mostram importações para arquivos que estão na mesma pasta e/ou para chamar funções do modulo "filho", mas eu quero executar o script como se estivesse rodando ele no prompt de comando. Quando eu abro o prompt de cmd e digito `python main.py -u ABDC -p 1234` funciona normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para executar o script .py você precisa chamar o interpretador **python**

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd = r"python /caminho/para/a/pasta/main.py -username abcd -password 1234"
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import os

if(os.name == "nt"):
    os.system("python3 covid19/san_covid19(Windows).py")
else:
    os.system("python3 covid19/'san_covid19(linux).py'")
```

Exemplo de um algoritmo, funciona no diretório windows e linux.
A importação de os faz com que execute no dois sistema operativos